# How to Unit Test Exceptions in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mocking

I am trying to write a unit test that tests if the exception is thrown, but I am not entirely sure how to do that.

Here is the code:

```
class GpsInfo {

    private lateinit var locationManager : LocationManager

    fun getGpsInfo(activity: Activity) : Location? {
        locationManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        var gpsCoordinates: Location
        try {
            gpsCoordinates = getGpsCoordinatesFromGpsProvider(locationManager)
        } catch(e: UnableAccessGPSProvider) {
            gpsCoordinates = getGpsCoordinatesFromNetwork(locationManager)
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            throw UnableGetGpsCoordinates("Cant get GPS coordinates")
        }

        return gpsCoordinates
    }

    private fun getGpsCoordinatesFromGpsProvider(locationManager: LocationManager) : Location {
        val gpsCoordinates = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        if (gpsCoordinates == null) {
            throw UnableAccessGPSProvider("Cant get GPS coordinates from GPS Provider")
        }
        return gpsCoordinates
    }

    private fun getGpsCoordinatesFromNetwork(locationManager: LocationManager) : Location {
        val gpsCoordinates = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
        if (gpsCoordinates == null) {
            throw UnableAccessNetwork("Cant get GPS coordinates from network")
        }
        return gpsCoordinates
    }
```

And here my sad unit testing attempt, I am trying to achieve it with a mockking class:

```
import android.app.Activity
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.junit.*
import kotlin.test.assertFailsWith

class GpsServiceUnitTest {
    private val gps = mockk<GpsInfo>()

    @Before
    fun iniz() {
        every { gps.getGpsInfo(Activity()) } throws UnableAccessGPSProvider("No GPS found")
    }

    @Test
    fun testFails() {
        assertFailsWith(UnableAccessGPSProvider::class) {
            gps.getGpsInfo(Activity())
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? I need to feed the function something so it would throw the exception, but I don't see how this would work.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to mock an `Activity` to `getGpsInfo()`? I see you've already known the technicalities of asserting `Exception`. And also why do you mock a method you want to test, i.e. `getGpsInfo()`?

Comment: Basically I am asking how to test my exceptions. What I have shown is just what I have come up with, I am sorry of that is irritating. Mocking an activity sounds promising tho.

Comment: No need to be sorry, I just wanted to clarify the problem. I think it's simpler to pass `LocationManager` to `getGpsInfo(…)` instead of `Activity`. To test you will then need to `mock locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(…) return null`. After that you can have `fun testGpsProviderFails` and `testGpsNetworkFails` that assert your Exceptions.

Comment: You were absolutely right. With your and Neos comment I was able to get it working. I passed locationManager instead of the activity and passed a mocked LocationManager. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid mocking a class you're trying to test, since you want to see the "real" behaviour.

My first step would be to slightly change your class and move field `locationManager` to constructor:

```
class GpsInfo(private val locationManager : LocationManager) {

    fun getGpsInfo(): Location? {
        var gpsCoordinates: Location
        try {
            gpsCoordinates = getGpsCoordinatesFromGpsProvider(locationManager)
        } catch (e: UnableAccessGPSProvider) {
            gpsCoordinates = getGpsCoordinatesFromNetwork(locationManager)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw UnableGetGpsCoordinates("Cant get GPS coordinates")
        }

        return gpsCoordinates
    }

    private fun getGpsCoordinatesFromGpsProvider(locationManager: LocationManager): Location {
        val gpsCoordinates = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        if (gpsCoordinates == null) {
            throw UnableAccessGPSProvider("Cant get GPS coordinates from GPS Provider")
        }
        return gpsCoordinates
    }

    private fun getGpsCoordinatesFromNetwork(locationManager: LocationManager): Location {
        val gpsCoordinates = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
        if (gpsCoordinates == null) {
            throw UnableAccessNetwork("Cant get GPS coordinates from network")
        }
        return gpsCoordinates
    }
}
```

Now you can mock the field easily to make it throw an exception:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.doThrow
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.catchThrowable

@Test
fun `should throw UnableGetGpsCoordinates exception`() {
    val locationManagerMock : LocationManager = mock {
        on { getLastKnownLocation(any()) } doThrow UnableAccessGPSProvider()
    }

    val throwable = catchThrowable { GpsInfo(locationManagerMock).getGpsInfo() }

    assertThat(throwable).isNotNull()
}
```

You could also leave `locationManager` as method parameter and mock it for the test, but it would require more effort to test it then, because we would have to mock two times - the activity and the `.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)` call.

BTW: I recommend using [nhaarman library for mocking](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) and [assertJ for asserting](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/)

Comment: This was the right way! Passing a locationManager makes way more sense than the activity now that I look at it. Anyway, mocking the LocationManager was the right attempt and I got it working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[`JUnit Jupiter`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) allows to test throwing Exceptions by using [`assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows-java.lang.Class-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-) method. Example:

```
assertThrows<UnableAccessGPSProvider> { GpsInfo(locationManagerMock).getGpsInfo() }
```

This assertion checks whether `getGpsInfo` throws `UnableAccessGPSProvider` exception.